How to solve numerical stability issue on hand craft NN?
I try to craft an NN from scratch using Numpy.
When I try to run it, the loss goes to the nan value after a few epochs, also the loss increases instead of decreasing. Am I doing something wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!
Below is my code
import numpy as np

def relu(z):
    g = np.maximum(0,z)
    return g

def relu_derivative(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, 1, 0)

def softmax(z): 
    z -= np.max(z, axis=1, keepdims=True)# Subtract max for numerical stability
    exp_z = np.exp(z)
    g = exp_z / np.sum(exp_z, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return g

def init_parameters(input_feature_size, hidden_0_size, hidden_1_size, output_size):
  # Storage weight from all three layers into a single dictronary
  W = {
      'W_0': np.random.randn(hidden_0_size, input_feature_size) * np.sqrt(2. / input_feature_size),
      'W_1': np.random.randn(hidden_1_size, hidden_0_size) * np.sqrt(2. / hidden_0_size),
      'W_2': np.random.randn(output_size, hidden_1_size) * np.sqrt(2. / hidden_1_size)
  }
  # Storage bias from all three layers into a single dictronary
  B = {
      'B_0': np.zeros((1, hidden_0_size)),
      'B_1': np.zeros((1, hidden_1_size)),
      'B_2': np.zeros((1, output_size,))
  }
  return W, B

def categorical_cross_entropy(probs, y_true):
    num_examples = probs.shape[0]
    probs = np.clip(probs, 1e-10, 1 - 1e-10)  # Clip predicted values to avoid log(0)
    log_probs = -np.log(probs[range(num_examples), y_true.flatten()])
    cost = np.sum(log_probs) / num_examples
    return cost

def forward_propagation(X, W, B):
  # Layer 1
  z0 = np.dot(X, W['W_0'].T) + B['B_0']
  a0 = relu(z0)

  # Layer 2
  z1 = np.dot(a0, W['W_1'].T) + B['B_1']
  a1 = relu(z1)
 
  # Layer 3
  z2 = np.dot(a1, W['W_2'].T) + B['B_2']
  a2 = softmax(z2)

  cache = {"z0": z0, "a0": a0, "z1": z1, "a1": a1, "z2": z2, "a2": a2}
  return a2, cache

def backward_propagation(X, Y, W, B, cache):
  m = X.shape[0]
  A0 = cache['a0']
  A1 = cache['a1']
  A2 = cache['a2']
  Z0 = cache['z0']
  Z1 = cache['z1']
  Z2 = cache['z2']
  # Layer output
  dJ_dZ2 = (A2 - Y)/m
  dJ_dW2 = np.dot(A1.T, dJ_dZ2)
  dJ_dB2 = np.sum(dJ_dZ2, axis=0, keepdims=True)

  # Layer hidden 1
  dJ_dA1 = np.dot(dJ_dZ2, W['W_2'])
  dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dA1 * relu_derivative(A1)
  dJ_dW1 = np.dot(A0.T, dJ_dZ1)
  dJ_dB1 = np.sum(dJ_dZ1, axis=0, keepdims=True)

  # Layer hidden 0
  dJ_dA0 = np.dot(dJ_dZ1, W['W_1'])
  dJ_dZ0 = dJ_dA0 * relu_derivative(A0)
  dJ_dW0 = np.dot(X.T, dJ_dZ0)
  dJ_dB0 = np.sum(dJ_dZ0, axis=0, keepdims=True)

  gradient = {"dw0":dJ_dW0, "db0":dJ_dB0, "dw1":dJ_dW1, "db1":dJ_dB1, "dw2":dJ_dW2, "db2":dJ_dB2}
  return gradient

def update_parameters(W, B, gradient, learning_rate):
  # Update weight
  W['W_0'] -= learning_rate * gradient['dw0'].T
  W['W_1'] -= learning_rate * gradient['dw1'].T
  W['W_2'] -= learning_rate * gradient['dw2'].T

  # Update bias
  B['B_0'] -= learning_rate * gradient['db0']
  B['B_1'] -= learning_rate * gradient['db1']
  B['B_2'] -= learning_rate * gradient['db2']
  return W, B

def train_nn(X, Y, input_feature_size, hidden_0_size, hidden_1_size, output_size, num_epochs=1000, learning_rate=0.01):

    W, B = init_parameters(input_feature_size, hidden_0_size, hidden_1_size, output_size)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Forward propagation
        A2, cache = forward_propagation(X, W, B)

        # Compute cost
        cost = categorical_cross_entropy(A2, Y)

        # Backward propagation
        gradients = backward_propagation(X, Y, W, B, cache)
        #gradients = clip_gradients(gradients, 10)

        # Update parameters
        W, B = update_parameters(W, B, gradients, learning_rate)
        if np.isnan(cost):
                print(f"NaN detected in cost at epoch {epoch}")
                break
        if epoch % 1 == 0 or epoch == num_epochs - 1:
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {cost}")

    return W, B


def clip_gradients(gradients, threshold):
    for key, value in gradients.items():
        gradients[key] = np.clip(value, -threshold, threshold)
    return gradients

data_path = Path.cwd()
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jldz9/DL_tutorial/main/data/00_Build_FCNN/X.npy
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jldz9/DL_tutorial/main/data/00_Build_FCNN/y.npy
X_train = np.load(data_path.joinpath('X.npy'))
Y_real = np.load(data_path.joinpath('y.npy'))
print("Shape of X_train is", X_train.shape) #(5000,400)
input_feature_size = X_train.shape[1] # X_train has 400 features for each picture
hidden_0_size = 25
hidden_1_size = 15
output_size = 10

W, B = train_nn(X_train, Y_real, input_feature_size, hidden_0_size, hidden_1_size, output_size, num_epochs=1000, learning_rate=0.01)

I tried different ways to increase the number stability but does not work.
I except it has the similar result as using a PyTorch by
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size_0, hidden_size_1, output_size):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size_0)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_0, hidden_size_1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size_1, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)  # Softmax activation
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x


X_train = np.load(data_path.joinpath('X.npy'))
Y_real = np.load(data_path.joinpath('y.npy'))
input_size = X_train.shape[1]
hidden_size_0 = 25
hidden_size_1 = 15
output_size = 10
model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size_0, hidden_size_1, output_size)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
num_epochs = 1000
X_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_train).float().to('cpu')
Y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(Y_real.flatten()).long().to('cpu')

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Forward pass
    outputs = model(X_train_tensor)
    loss = criterion(outputs, Y_train_tensor)
    
    # Backward pass and optimization
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    # Print the loss every 100 epochs
    if (epoch+1) % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

# Save the trained model if needed
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'trained_model.pth')


Hard to say but my guess is the instability comes from the softmax. You want to use log softmax with the max logit value subtracted. See this for more details
